# Quiet makefile not working

Tags: makefile

So I've a recursive makefile that's on a project, but for some reason, AR is the only command that still prints output.

How can I force it to be quiet? It has already '@' at the beginning, and I don't want to pipe the output to null.

How i'm calling this makefile?

```
@cd libc; make clean --no-print-directory
```

Here's the troublemaker makefile:

```
include ../Makefile.inc

LIB=../libc.a
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
SOURCES_ASM=$(wildcard asm/*.asm)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS_ASM=$(SOURCES_ASM:.asm=.o)

all: $(LIB)
    @echo -e "  libC        [ \033[0;32mOK \033[0m]"

$(LIB): $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS_ASM)
    @$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) -c $(LIB) $(OBJECTS_ASM) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

$(OBJECTS_ASM): $(SOURCES_ASM)

%.o: %.c
    @$(GCC) $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    @$(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o ../*.a

.PHONY:
    all clean
```

and here's the output:

```
a - asm/syscall.o
a - syscall.o
a - string.o
a - stdio.o
a - integer.o
    libC        [ OK ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `@` just prevents `make` from printing the command before executing it. It does nothing about output from the command itself.

Comment: Oh stupid me. Is there a way to redirect the stdout to null, but only part of it and not all?

Comment: Pipe it into a program that chooses what to swallow and what to pass on to stdout. E.g. if it's lines with certain patterns you want to keep, `grep` is the obvious choice.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `ar` to print output then stop telling it to do so! :)

Since you haven't shown any setting for `ARFLAGS` I assume you're using the default value, which in GNU make is `rv` and the `v` flag means "verbose" (see `man ar`).

So, just setting:

```
ARFLAGS = r
```

in your makefile should turn off the verbose output from `ar`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to simply redirect the stdout to a log file for AR command only, as follows:

```
@$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) -c $(LIB) $(OBJECTS_ASM) $(OBJECTS) >> $(LOG_FILE)
```

It keeps the errors displayed because it does not redirect stderr.